# Clojure - pairs from nested lists

Tags: list, dictionary, clojure, nested

I'm trying to make traversing nested lists to collect pairs more idiomatic in Clojure

```
(def mylist '(
  (2, 4, 6)
  (8, 10, 12)))

(defn pairs [[a b c]]
  (list (list a c)(list b c)))

(mapcat pairs mylist)

;((2 6) (4 6) (8 12) (10 12))
```

Can this be made more elegant?

Comment: what is the logic behind pairing? why there is no `(2 4)` pair?

Comment: They represent cartesian coordinates of equal height. (x1, x2, y) => (x1, y) (x2, y).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is good, but I would use vectors instead of lists

```
(defn pairs [[x1 x2 y]]
  [[x1 y] [x2 y]])

(mapcat pairs mylist)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add more solutions (not elegant or intuitive; do not use ;) ):

```
(mapcat
  (juxt (juxt first last) (juxt second last))
  [[2 4 6] [8 10 12]])
;; => ([2 6] [4 6] [8 12] [10 12])
```

Or this one:

```
(mapcat
  #(for [x (butlast %) y [(last %)]] [x y])
  [[2 4 6] [8 10 12]])
;; => ([2 6] [4 6] [8 12] [10 12])
```

Comment: that's pretty awesome